# Как возвращать одно и то же значение в двух случаях Case?

Tags: javascript, switch

У меня небольшой вопрос по поводу switch и его кейсов. Что если при разных вводных данных я хочу получить одно и то же значение? Например, в моём случае CC которые определяються по первым цифрам. У меня получилось пару копипастов, а хотелось бы использовать один кэйс в случае идентификации VISA (от 51 до 55) и т.д.

```
function getPaymentSystem(typeCard) {
  switch (typeCard) {
    case 4:
      return 'VISA';

    case 67:
      return 'Maestro';

    case 1234:
      return 'unknown payment system';

    case 37:
      return 'American Express';

    case 34:
      return 'American Express';

    case 52:
      return 'MasterCard';

    case 55:
      return 'MasterCard';
  }
}
```

Comment: case 37 : case 34: return ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то так:

```
function getPaymentSystem(typeCard) {
  switch (typeCard) {
    case 4:
      return 'VISA';

    case 67:
      return 'Maestro';

    case 1234:
      return 'unknown payment system';

    case 37:

    case 34:
      return 'American Express';

    case 52:

    case 55:
      return 'MasterCard';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kromster я скопировал вопрос в ответ. Так-то понятно что по чем. Спс